# declaring variables in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to define a variable conn in my controller.js.

With the code at the bottom, I get lots of horrible UI glitches, so I'm presuming the code below is wrong. If I try:

```
var conn;
conn.name = 'Fred';
```

I get what looks like a NullPointer Error "Cannot set property 'name' of undefined" when I attempt to set conn.name.

How do I define my variable?

```
var addDBConnControllerBase = app.controller('addDBConnControllerBase',
function($scope,$http,serviceFactory,$modal,$location,$log)
{
    $scope.saveDBConn = function()
    {
        var conn = {
            name,
            driverType,
            connectionString,
            userID,
            password
        };
        conn.name = $scope.addDBConnController.displayName;
        conn.driverType = $scope.addDBConnController.driverType;
        conn.connectionString = $scope.addDBConnController.connectionString;
        conn.userID = $scope.addDBConnController.userID;
        conn.password = $scope.addDBConnController.password;
        $log.debug('Saving db conn');
        $log.debug(JSON.stringify(conn));
    }
});
```

Comment: I would use a service for saving connection settings. It's more "angular-way"

Comment: Using a service is the second part of my task. This is angular day 1 for me and I was just making sure I could get the data from the screen to the controller to start with. :-)

Comment: [] is an array. {} is an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newAttrs = {};
newAttrs[nameOfProp] = valueOfProp;
```

try this!!!

In your case I think this would be

```
var conn = {};
conn["name"] = 'Fred';
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to brush up on your javascript pronto! This:

```
var conn;
```

is a variable declaration, not definition. `conn` is still `undefined` after this statement so you can't go `conn.name = ...`. You have to initialize things before you use them:

```
var conn = {};
conn.name = ...
```

or

```
var conn = {
  name: ...
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should define variable **conn** as an array first. Like following.

```
var conn = [];
conn.name=$scope.addDBConnController.displayName;
```

Comment: Eeeeerrr, [] is not how you initialize objects.

Comment: I don't need an array. But thanks anyway. I learned something new :-)

Comment: [] is an  array, {} is an object.